# Bootstrap I want to have a five column layout on desktop but two columns on mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, responsive-design

I want 20 buttons in 4x5 fashion on desktop but on mobile 10x2 fashion. Here is my [jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pcchxjbs/1)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <button type="button" style="background-color:white" class="btn btn-default btn-square">white</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#F7F6E4" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Beige</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#3BA6F8" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Blau</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#F36660" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Rot</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#FDFCEA" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Creme</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#DBDBDB" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Graue</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#E6C08E" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Eiche</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#358B9F" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Petrol</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#FF7ECD" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Rosa</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#C9C9C9" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Silber</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#505558;color:white;" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Anthrazit</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:C39881" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Taupe</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#569A9E" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Trukis</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#A03A97" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Lila</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#FFDB53" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Gold</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#2E2E2E;color:white;" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Schwarz</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#A16340" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Braun</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#C9DDA8" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Grun</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#FFB24A" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Orange</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#FFFD5E" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Gelb</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I could not find anything useful online. I am not using any trick here. Basically I am using button sizes so that it appears in 5 column and then it should appear in 2 column on mobile, but it does not work.

Comment: and what about upgrading to V4 of bootstrap ? it will be easy

Comment: I would prefer v3 solution but if v4 solutions exists, why not! thanks

Comment: There are many ways to obtain this, in both Bootstrap v3 and v4. While definitely easier in v4 out of the box, customizing Bootstrap to use a custom number of columns is fairly straight forward, if you look it up. If you don't want this change site-wide, you can always override the width of a particular (set of) column(s), using a parent selector to limit this override to desired section. *"I couldn't find anything useful online"* does not qualify as decent research. In current form the question looks like you don't feel like working today and thought you'd chance it here, maybe you get lucky.

Comment: fixed 'col-med-12'. Well I thought this would be easy but it is tricker than what I thought. If you an find a quick solution, shy not share a link. I could not find any (not that I spend days on it).

Comment: I'm afraid I misread your question. I just realized you don't want a 5 columns layout, as the title says, but a 4 columns layout, as the body of the question says. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: No 5 column, first number is rows, second column, 5x4 into 2x10

Comment: I found the answer you're looking for, using minimal CSS and dividing contents of 5th column in 2. Have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to write less code and avoid so many `col-*` classes...Use **Flexbox**

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/pcchxjbs/3/)**

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.btn-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.btn.btn-square {
  flex: 0 0 calc(20% - 10px);
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 5px;
}

@media (max-width:576px) {
  .btn.btn-square {
    flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<h1 class="text-center">Bootstrap Buttons</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div class="btn-row">
    <button type="button" style="background-color:white" class="btn btn-default btn-square col-md">white</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#F7F6E4" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Beige</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#3BA6F8" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Blau</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#F36660" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Rot</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#FDFCEA" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Creme</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#DBDBDB" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Graue</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#E6C08E" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Eiche</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#358B9F" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Petrol</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#FF7ECD" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Rosa</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#C9C9C9" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Silber</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#505558;color:white;" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Anthrazit</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:C39881" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Taupe</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#569A9E" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Trukis</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#A03A97" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Lila</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#FFDB53" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Gold</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#2E2E2E;color:white;" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Schwarz</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#A16340" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Braun</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#C9DDA8" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Grun</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#FFB24A" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Orange</button>
    <button type="button" style="background-color:#FFFD5E" class="btn btn-default btn-square">Gelb</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Using bootstrap3**

With bootstrap3 you have to use `col-offset` class to align 5 elements in a row.

**[Fiddle Link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/bhuwanb9/jLkxdubt/1/)**

---

Comment: really nice, however is it possible to do it in pure bootstrap

Comment: @hmd In bootstrap4 it is very easy....but for bootstrap3 you have to write extra code as in bootstrap3 no `col-*` class comes with `width:20%`....you have to make your own custom class for this..

Comment: Can you provide a separate answer in bootstrap 4?

Comment: @hmd The above solution uses bootstrap4 concept....You can find more on bootstrap grid.....https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: @hmd In bootstrap4 there is no class for `width:20%` either...So you have to write custom in bootstrap4 case also....the thing is that bootstrap4 also uses `flexbox` layout, so its become easy to align items in it...I hope it will help you..

Comment: @hmd I have added another solution using bootstrap3...Have a look

Comment: Nice, I little explanation regarding col-offset might help though.

Comment: @hmd you can read the official doc here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-offsetting

Answer (score 0):

What you want is custom. The only question is: do you want this change in columns widths to apply to all pages/columns or to a particular section of your site?

For site-wide changing number of columns, go to https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/#grid-system, change `12` to `10` and download the result.

If you only want it applying on a particular section, first of all add a `.row` between `.container` and `.col-*-*` (it's quite important). Secondly, add a class to your `.row`, to distinguish it from other `.row`s in your website. For this example, I used the class `10-cols`:

And add this to your CSS, to override the width of those cols:

```
.\31\30-cols > * {
  width: 50%;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .\31\30-cols > * {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```

However, there still seems to be a logical problem. You say you want the buttons divided as: 5 x 4 on large and 2 x 10 on small. Great. Let's take the contents of each of your columns from large and arrange them nicely in two columns on mobile. We put first, third, and fifth columns on left and second and fourth on right. But you want the contents of 5th to be divided in both columns, right?

<strike>So you probably want to put all your buttons inside one single element and either use flexbox or CSS columns to display them as you want.</strike>

So you need to display this column as full width on mobile and further divide its contents in two columns:

```css
.\31\30-cols > [class^="col-md"] {
  width: 50%;
}

.\31\30-cols > .col-xs-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .\31\30-cols > [class^="col-md"] {
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row 10-cols">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-6">
      <button type="button" style="background-color:white" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">white</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#F7F6E4" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Beige</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#3BA6F8" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Blau</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#F36660" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Rot</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-6">
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#FDFCEA" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Creme</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#DBDBDB" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Graue</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#E6C08E" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Eiche</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#358B9F" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Petrol</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-6">
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#FF7ECD" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Rosa</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#C9C9C9" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Silber</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#505558;color:white;" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Anthrazit</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:C39881" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Taupe</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-6">
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#569A9E" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Trukis</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#A03A97" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Lila</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#FFDB53" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Gold</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#2E2E2E;color:white;" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Schwarz</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
          <button type="button" style="background-color:#A16340" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Braun</button>
          <button type="button" style="background-color:#C9DDA8" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Grun</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
          <button type="button" style="background-color:#FFB24A" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Orange</button>
          <button type="button" style="background-color:#FFFD5E" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Gelb</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

As a side-note, given the order of the buttons is not really important, the sane method here would have been to put all the buttons in one column and arrange them using either flexbox:

```css
.\31\30-cols .col-xs-12 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.\31\30-cols .col-xs-12 .btn {
  flex: 1 0 calc(50% - 20px);
  margin: 5px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .\31\30-cols .col-xs-12 .btn {
    flex-basis: calc(20% - 10px);
  }
}
```

```css
.\31\30-cols .col-xs-12 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.\31\30-cols .col-xs-12 .btn {
  flex: 1 0 calc(50% - 20px);
  margin: 5px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .\31\30-cols .col-xs-12 .btn {
    flex-basis: calc(20% - 10px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row 10-cols">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button type="button" style="background-color:white" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">white</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#F7F6E4" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Beige</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#3BA6F8" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Blau</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#F36660" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Rot</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#FDFCEA" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Creme</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#DBDBDB" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Graue</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#E6C08E" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Eiche</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#358B9F" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Petrol</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#FF7ECD" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Rosa</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#C9C9C9" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Silber</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#505558;color:white;" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Anthrazit</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:C39881" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Taupe</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#569A9E" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Trukis</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#A03A97" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Lila</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#FFDB53" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Gold</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#2E2E2E;color:white;" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Schwarz</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#A16340" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Braun</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#C9DDA8" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Grun</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#FFB24A" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Orange</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#FFFD5E" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Gelb</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or CSS columns:

```css
.\31\30-cols .col-xs-12 {
  columns: 2;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .\31\30-cols .col-xs-12 {
    columns: 5;
  }
}
```

```css
.\31\30-cols .col-xs-12 {
  columns: 2;
  column-gap: 10px;
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .\31\30-cols .col-xs-12 {
    columns: 5;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row 10-cols">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button type="button" style="background-color:white" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">white</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#F7F6E4" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Beige</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#3BA6F8" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Blau</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#F36660" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Rot</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#FDFCEA" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Creme</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#DBDBDB" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Graue</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#E6C08E" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Eiche</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#358B9F" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Petrol</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#FF7ECD" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Rosa</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#C9C9C9" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Silber</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#505558;color:white;" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Anthrazit</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:C39881" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Taupe</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#569A9E" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Trukis</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#A03A97" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Lila</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#FFDB53" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Gold</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#2E2E2E;color:white;" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Schwarz</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#A16340" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Braun</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#C9DDA8" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Grun</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#FFB24A" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Orange</button>
      <button type="button" style="background-color:#FFFD5E" class="btn btn-block btn-default btn-square">Gelb</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```